# Get record according to country name mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello everyone i am working with mysql and PHP. I have a table name `Doctors` and i want to know how many doctors in which country ( count ) , Here is my database

```
id      doctor_id       name        address
1       101             abc         Sector 8C, Chandigarh, India, 160008
2       102             xyz         México, Chis., Mexico
3       103             yty         Sector 22, Begum Pur, Delhi, 110086, India
4       104             bhw         1018 Market St, Philadelphia, PA 19107, USA
5       105             byr         Sector 22, Begum Pur, Delhi, 110086, India
6       106             jue         Panama City Beach, FL, USA
```

I tried with following query but not working properly

```
SELECT address,COUNT(*) FROM doctors GROUP BY address
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: You need to separate country from address into another column.

Comment: Your format of addresses is not consistent, so it will be difficult to determine which is the country. You could store countries and state in a separate column, and the address in one.

Comment: @PavelTřupek: i can understand but is there any other solution ?

Comment: _is there any other solution ?..._ read over [normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Comment: @snehapathak no, how else could you decide, what of the address is country?

Comment: usually state, region, zip, and country are on a separate column, address are dedicated for street, unit names and the like. now you're in a painful mess

Comment: i'd suggest take your time to fix your database structure and follow normalization rules to avoid yourself some technical debt which you are having right now. avoid band aid solutions while early.

Comment: Can you create one more column-like ( country or country_id ) to get records, So you can easily find by country.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is in very bad format, you can't apply any rule to extract country and group by it. So the closest you can get is to get count for specific country:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM doctors
WHERE INSTR(address, 'country you want to get count for') > -1
```